# Find the formula for the..

Tags: sequences-and-series

For the following, find the formula for the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence
$$1,3,6,10,.........................$$.

My Attempt:
$$t_1=1=(1-1)+1$$

$$t_2=3=(2-1)+2$$

$$t_3=6=(3-1)+3$$.

The answer in my book is $$(n-1)+n$$ but it doesn't match with $$t_3, t_4$$.

I tried a lot thinking about it but could not figure out.

Can anyone help me with the correct formula?

Comment: $\frac {n(n+1)}2$.  These are the Triangular Numbers

Comment: These are triangular numbers. $t_n$ is simply the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $n$.  It is easy to see that $t_n = n(n+1)/2$, for example if $n$ is even, say $n=10$, you can group the numbers from to $10$ in $10/2=5$ pairs whose sum is always $10+1=11$, i.e., $(1,10)$, $(2,9)$, $(3,8)$,  $(4,7)$, and $(5,6)$.  Generalizing this reasoning you can see that if $n$ is even you can split the numbers into $n/2$ pairs whose sum is $n+1$, thus $t_n=n(n+1)/2$. You make a similar reasoning when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Did the book say that $t_n = t_{n - 1} + n$?  Along with stating that $t_1 = 1$, that would constitute a recursive definition of the sequence formed by adding the first $n$ positive integers.

Comment: @ N.F.Taussig, the book hasnot explained anything like that.

Comment: There is no correct answer to the question since knowing the first $n$ terms of a sequence tells you nothing about the subsequent terms unless you are given a rule to form the subsequent terms.

Comment: There are infinitely many formulas that match any given finite sequence, so there is no sinlge correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the difference of each term is in A.P, like, (3-1 = 2), (6-3 = 3), (10-6 = 4).

So, we can clearly observe that the difference of the terms are in A.P (2, 3, 4).

Thus, I can assume the $n^{th}$ term to be $$t_n = an^2 + bn + c$$.

So, we have, $$t_1 = a + b + c = 1$$ $$t_2 = 4a + 2b + c = 3$$ $$t_3 = 9a + 3b + c = 6$$.

Now, on solving these equations, we will get $$a = \frac 12, \ b = \frac 12, \ c = 0$$.

Therefore, the $n^{th}$ term will be -- $$t_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$.

Comment: How can you say that the difference of the terms are in $A.P$.

Comment: I have showed you the difference of the terms, i.e, **(2, 3, 4)** which is an **A.P**. with common difference 1.

Comment: This is a rule of Sequence and series, if the difference of terms at level 1 is in A.P then nth term will be of quadratic form, if ithe difference at level 2 is in A.P., then nth term will be of cubic form and so on.

Comment: What if the difference of terms are in G.P?